# node.js mongoose find() not value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

route/signup.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const User = require('../model/user');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


function userFind(value){
    return User.find({user_id:value}).exec();
};



router.get('/',function (req,res) {

    res.render('login/signup');


});


router.post('/',async function (req,res,next){
    try{
    let userid =req.body.id;
    console.log(userid);   //abcdefg
    const user = await userFind(userid);
    console.log(user);     // []
    
}catch(err){

    next(err);

    } 
})

module.exports = router;
```

model/user.js

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
   const userSchema = new Schema(
       { user_id  : {type:String,required:true, unique:true},
     user_password : {type:String, required:true, select:false},
     user_name: {type:String, required:true},
     user_email : {type:String,required:true,unique : true},
     user_birth : {type:String,require:true},
     },{versionKey:false},
     {collection: 'user'}
     );

module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

data inside mongodb.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60413c7c48e5e61187cc4eeb"
  },
  "user_id": "abcdefg",
  "user_password": "test111",
  "user_name": "세글자",
  "user_email": "test@naver.com",
  "user_birth": "884455"
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function(){
    // CONNECTED TO MONGODB SERVER
    console.log("Connected to mongod server");
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://testing1:7894@cluster0.9hxjc.mongodb.net/data? 
   retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: 
true });

var app = express();

var test = require('./route/index');
var test2 = require('./route/signup');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');  // == 
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use('/',test);
app.use('/signup.ejs',test2);

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

Hello, I am studying using mogoose and node.js. I ran mongoose find() but the result was only []. I don't know why this is so, I would appreciate it if you let me know. And if it is findOne(), how should I write it? I tried writing it once, but it turned out to be null.

Comment: what is it that you are showing under "mongodb" in your question? Is that the output from `db.users.find()` in the mongodb shell? Can you also add the code where you connect mongoose to your database?

Comment: @Christian Fritz   Thanks for the answer, I also added a part that connects to the database. What is displayed under 'mongodb' is a written down of the data stored in the db.

Comment: The db contains potentially multiple collections. I want to make sure it's the correct one. Can you verify it's the 'users' collection you are showing the content of?

Comment: @Christian Fritz  Thank you! It was a collection problem! I created a collection called'user' and stored data there. However, a collection called'users' has been created! Why did this happen? Apparently, the collection was designated as'user' in the model.

Comment: In mongoose, when the model is called 'user' the collection will be 'users' (plural).

Comment: @Christian Fritz Thank you so much for your kind response.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I wrote up the solution as an answer, so people know it's resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through chatting in comments we found the issue. The model is called `user`:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

Which mongoose will connect to a collection named `users` (plural) in MongoDB. That collection was indeed empty. There was only content in a collection named `user`.